# asp.net mvc application logging me out almost randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hosting

The application works fine when running locally, but when i upload it to the hosting (123-reg) and log in, the Authentication Cookie is made, and i can navigate the site for a few seconds, then i'm redirected to the log in, but the authentication cookie still exists.

It logs out the user after random amounts of time, but only when on the hosting.

Answer (score 1):

After thorough searching I discovered that 123-Reg's IIS was generating an Automatic machine key for my Application and was then timing out.

If you generate one using [this](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Resources/MachineKey.aspx) and put in your `Web.config` file, It works!

Comment: You may have to update or remove this answer as the link is redirecting to an unrelated Japanese website?

Answer (score 0):

Is the app running in a cluster or load balance?

In that case you'll need to store session data in another server, It may be a SqlServer or an IIS.

Comment: Excuse me for my lack of experience, but im not sure which of this is i am running, is there a way i can tell?

Comment: Is this application running in more than one server?

Comment: I am running it locally and on the hosting server I have purchased.